# Which strategy is better to validate a csv line?

Tags: java

For simplicity, given a csv line with two fields: login and score from 0 by 100 for some passed test.

csv line examples

```
cool;95  
clever;900  
loser;10;-1  
freak;ten  
;50
```

The task is to validate a csv line.
I have two beans for a test result and a csv line.
I see 3 low level strategies for a csv line parsing.

Strategy 1. All checks are inside the csv line bean.

```
class CsvLine {
    private String csvLine;

    //constructors
    ... 

    public Result getResult() throws LineException {
        String[] fields = csvLine.split(";");
        if(fields.length != 2) {
            throw new LineException();
        }
        //other possible checks with csvLine and its fields
        ...
        //in the case everything is ok
        return new Result(login, score);        
    }
}

class Result {
    private String login; 
    private int score;

    //trivial constructor
    public Result(String login, int score) {
        this.login = login;
        this.score = score;
    }
    ...
}
```

Strategy 2. All checks are inside the result bean.

```
class CsvLine {
    ... 
    public Result getResult() throws LineException {
        return new Result(csvLine);     
    }
}

class Result {
    ...
    public Result(String csvLine) throws LineException {
        String[] fields = csvLine.split(";");
        if(fields.length != 2) {
            throw new LineException();  //own exception
        }
        this.login = getLogin(fields[0]);   //private method with checks
        this.score = getScore(fields[1]);   //conversion and checks
    }
    ...
}
```

Strategy 3. Checks for the line structure are inside the csv line bean and checks for fields validness are inside the result bean.

```
class CsvLine {
    ... 
    public Result getResult() throws LineException {
        String[] fields = csvLine.split(";");
        if(fields.length != 2) {
            throw new LineException();
        }
        try {
            return new Result(fields[0], new Integer(fields[1]).intValue());
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new LineException();
        }
    }
}

class Result {
    ...
    public Result(String login, int score) {
        if("".equals(login)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if(score < 0 || score > 100) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.login = login;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Complete validation of a csv line is located inside one and the same bean in strategies 1 and 2.
But each bean contains checks for its own fields and for fields of associated bean.
Meanwhile, in strategy 3, validation is located in proper way, but separated.

What to prefer?
Or do both approaches make sense?

Comment: Is throwing the LineException a requirement?

Comment: I'd say it's the way to notify the CsvLine client about the wrong line. 
Let's consider this notification be critical.

Answer (score 2):

There are two concepts one is **Fail-Fast** and another is **Fail-Safe**. All are not applicable in all situation, there is no rule of thumb that either one will be used. In some situations, **Fail-Fast** is perfectly ok and it is reasonable. **Fail-Safe** is also reasonable in some business use cases. So far your question is concerned, it brings two use cases.

1. First Validate and then Process
   In this case, you have the reason not to process unwanted/undesired csv lines so that you can save memory and further processing. In this case, Strategy-1 is good as it is a case of Fail-Fast.
2. Process and Handle exception gracefully.
   This is a case of **Fail-Safe**, if the requirement is is grab everything and maintain it even if the lines are not proper, then create another Strategy called Strategy-4 where you handle exception gracefully and maintain a list of valid objects for the next sub-system to process.

Comment: If he uses the first stragety he would neet to read the whole file into the memory (if it is valid). Depending on the file size that might not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose a different stategy.

Parsing of the File and it content should be in one place. Normally I'd say you do not want to spread this across multiple classes, so that might not be the case if you want to do some fancy parallel processing.

Another question would be how do you need to handle invalid lines? Reject the file alltogether or only take those lines that are valid? When you work with large amount of data you are bound to end up with some kind of inconsistency, yet you do not want to stop processing all of it.

Unless your are getting these CSVLine objects from somewhere, I would probably not bother to create them. But you might want to have some method for handling each line, which only returns the result or an exception in case the line is invalid.

---

In relation to `@Sambit` answers:
Be wary of the amount of content you need to process. If you need to handle larger files, then reading them completly into your memory is not advisable.
In that case you want to process the files in smaller parts, for example lines.

---

What you should end up with, is a class, where you can see that it`s responsible for processing the csv - name something like CSVParser and where you can see what content it's actually expecting and what validation it is doing. So all of that could be handled in a static way.

Something like this:

```
class CSVParser {

    private CSVParser() {
    }

    public final static class Result {  // immutable object

        public final String login; 
        public final int score;

        Result(String login, int score) {
            this.login = login;
            this.score = score;
        }
    }

   // LineException only if required else you might want to return a
   // different object containing the parsed lines in form of a result
   // and the invalid lines that could not be handled. Or you write them
   // to another file, and only give back the FileHandle ...
   // depends on the usecase (in that case get rid of the LineException alltogether).
    public static List<Result> parseFile(File file) throws IOException, LineException  {
        // file handling, calls line processing
    }

    static Result parseLine(String line) throws LineException {

         String[] columns = line.split(";");

         // validation checks, parsing and exception throwing here

         // result creation afterwards
         return new Result();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, _Parsing of the File and it content should be in one place_. 
And your strategy follows this idea. 
I consider its static implementation as a drawback. It can be fixed easily but that's not the point.   

Sorry, I see that my question needs some update.   

Focus of my attention is to separate parsing and validation of csv line content or not. 
I see in your code they are together as in the strategy 1. 
As for me strategy 3 where actions are cut off is better.